# Windows Live Movie Maker Output Video Quality Low

Tags: video-editor, windows, video-quality, screen-casting, freeware

I'm using Windows Live Movie Maker on Windows 7.

I made a screen capture video with a third party app which produces **.avi** files. Its quality is perfect. Its properties:

- Resolution: 1280 * 720 (720p)
- Frame Rate: 15
- Kbps: ~10.000
- Video Size: ~23 MB

I imported it to Movie Maker. And without any modification I just exported it with these settings:

[image]

The resulting video was 1.5 MB and of course in **.wmv** format.

The quality drastically lower.

Than I tried increasing frame rate (till 30), bit rate (til 60.000), resolution (till 1080p). No change!

I don't care about the size (in MB), I want a big high quality video.

I'll add lots of videos and do lots of editing and Windows Movie Maker is a very practical tool for an amateur like me.

So **is there a way to get a very high quality video from Movie Maker?**

Comment: Simple answer- no. It is a free, basic, home editor. Get a proper one and you'll be fine:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do much about it. Movie Maker can only export in WMV format - and WMV is created for small video sizes (at the cost of quality).

You will need another software package to export in other formats than WMV. Check out [Pinnacle products](http://www.pinnaclesys.com/PublicSite/us/Home/) for alternative - they target amateur producers.

Comment: I was going to try Pinnacle but a friend suggested to go with Adobe Premier Elements 11. Super easy editing, perfect export, just what I wanted (but...very problematic to install!). I guess "free" has its limits, but at least I learned some basics with Movie Maker... I think Movie Maker is still a very good tool... Thank you for directing me for my search.